# How to list the vertices over a selected edge in Maya via Python

Tags: python, scripting, maya, mel

I have a scenario, where I need to snap an `Object B` over the vertices of a selected edge of `Object A`.
I need to know, how to list all the vertices of a selected polyObject edge in a sequence, so that I can duplicate and snap the objects to required vertices based on my requirement. Like snap to every alternate vertex.

Your suggestions are so valuable to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `MEL` version:

```
polyCube -sx 1 -sy 1 -sz 1 ;
select -r pCube1.e[7] ;
PolySelectConvert 3 ;
select -d pCube1.e[7] ;
$allComponents = `ls -selection` ;
print ( $allComponents ) ;

// print ( $allComponents[0] ) ;
// print ( $allComponents[1] ) ;
```

This is a `Python` version:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

mc.polyCube( sx=1, sy=1, sz=1 )
mc.select( 'pCube1.e[7]' )
mc.select( mc.polyListComponentConversion( tv=True ) ) 
allComponents = mc.ls( sl=True )
print( allComponents )

# print( allComponents[0] )
# print( allComponents[1] )
```